# Performance: Video thumbnail / screenshot generation

Tags: ios, objective-c, mpmovieplayercontroller, avfoundation

I´m currently using MpMoviePlayerController thumbnailImageAtTime to grab a thumbnail of my video. However there seems to be a delay around 0.5 seconds when generating the thumbnail - I have some ideas on how to optimize this, but I was wondering if there might be any performance gain in using one of the lower level frameworks? (CoreMedia or AV Foundation)

I have read several answers on SO that claim that AV Foundation (by using AVAssetImageGenerator) will generate thumbnails faster than MpMoviePlayerController - but I have also found SO answers that state the opposite.

I am looking for a method for taking video thumbnails at a specified time without any delay. Is that possible by using any of the mentioned frameworks or do I need to look into other custom solutions? (i.e.: using ffmpeg or similar?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I went ahead and did some tests with the AV Foundation framework and AVAssetImageGenerator. Even when I set `requestedTimeToleranceAfter` and `requestedTimeToleranceBefore` to `kCMTimeZero` the AV foundation framework gave a very high performance gain compared to the higher level MpMoviePlayerController. For the purpose of my app I was able to achieve nearly realtime generation of thumbnails by using the AV Foundation framework.

Answer (score -1):

```
UIImage *Thumbnailimage = [YourmoviePlayer thumbnailImageAtTime:1.0   timeOption:MPMovieTimeOptionNearestKeyFrame];
```

Comment: Rajkurnar: I already know how to generate thumbnails, and I currently use the method you pasted - however I want to know if its possible to improve the performance of generating the thumbnail/screenshots.